# Omission of a verb?

Tags: phrases, verbs

This is from George Orwell's Down and Out in Paris and London:

> "Thereupon a whole variegated chorus of yells, as windows were flung
>   open on every side and half the street joined in the quarrel." (pg.1,
>   Penguin edition).

It is the first part - "Thereupon a variegated chorus of yells" - which I am interested in. I am under the impression that "chorus" is used here as a noun; therefore, there is no verb in the phrase at the beginning of the sentence, yet it gives the impression of a clause. If the sentence were as follows, "Thereupon a variegated chorus of yells.", it would still make sense to me despite the absence of any verb. Is a verb implied?: "Thereupon a variegated chorus of yells (erupted)", for example. If so, is there a name for this? I am sure I have seen it before.

Comment: I'd put the implied verb earlier: *"Thereupon [came] a variegated chorus of yells …"*

Comment: It is a [sentence fragment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143488/verbless-sentence/143494#143494). It is used here for dramatic effect, and is fine as it is easily understood and not overdone. Peter has suggested a possible verb; it doesn't add much meaningwise, though converts to the more normal sentence structure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't happen to think it is up to Orwell's usual standard. 'Variegated yells' don't arrive with you as a 'chorus', but as a 'cacophony'.

Comment: See the first three paragraphs of Dickens' Bleak House: http://www.online-literature.com/dickens/bleakhouse/2/

Comment: @WS2 Agreed – I'm not sure 'Down and Out in Paris and London' ever did fly. But then this _is_ the Penguin edition.

Comment: @PeterShor many thanks. Your post led me to the topic of sentence inversion. EdwinAshworth, I don't understand the Penguin Edition reference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Notwithstanding that, *Down and Out* was a 1930s' masterpiece. Originally written, one assumes, as two shorter novels -one re Paris where he was a *plongeur* in a restaurant; and the other re London, where he was a tramp. What was brilliant was how he adapted his writing to the quite different *zeitgeist* after the war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the verb is implied here. 
It implies that the chorus of yells came out or erupted as you said.

As in the sentence a bit before this sentence came up in the text - "A succession of furious, choking yells from the street." The sentence is not complete in itself.

Authors tend to use incomplete sentences as a form of style which we may find inapt but then, the book goes way back. We can't complain.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that Veronica. I didn't notice the preceding one. Just shows that they are familiar, I guess. Is there a term for this? It looks like a form of ellipsis, but I can't find a more specific name.

Comment: I haven't come across a proper term for such sentences. Sorry, Won't be able to help much from here. Could you accept my answer if it helped to answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

Technically it is not an omission but the 'flowerizing' speech:

**[Antemereia](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/122978)**:

> In rhetoric, anthimeria (traditionally and more properly called
>   antimeria) is the use of a word as if it were a member of a different
>   word class (part of speech); typically, the use of a noun as if it
>   were a verb.

Comment: Which non-verb word is being used a verb here, then?