# Understanding why this is a complete sentence: 'Not happy or content.'

Tags: sentence, sentence-fragments, grammaticality

I'm perplexed why the grammar check considers this a grammatically complete sentence:

- Not happy or content.

To me, it's missing both a subject and a verb.  Could someone shed some light on this for me? Thanks.

Comment: Does the grammar checker have a "complete sentence" indicator?  Even if it is not a complete sentence, "Not happy or content" could be included in writing anyway.

Comment: It is not a complete sentence. As to why the grammar checker considers it that, we'd have to understand the inner workings of that tool. I'd just accept the fact that the tool is incomplete and incorrect.

Comment: What's missing for me is any context. Who wrote this, where is it from? What is the surrounding text?  A fragment on its own can't be analysed grammatically. Please give more information.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, and confirmation it's a fragment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verbless sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143488/verbless-sentence) (1) Your example is a fragment rather than a sentence according to the subject + finite verb requirement. (2) It may or may not be acceptable as an utterance or in a novel say, depending on context. (3) **_If_** rendered acceptable by context, there are those who will say that it qualifies as a sentence on _semantic_ grounds (obviously using a different definition of 'sentence').