# What is it called when an author uses a question mark without a question attached?

Tags: questions, question-mark

My specific example is from a passage in Fahrenheit 451 (although I've seen it used colloquially as well):

> Click? Pic? Look, Eye, Now, Flick, Here, There, Swift, Pace, Up, Down, In, Out, Why, How, Who, What, Where, Eh? Uh! Bang! Smack! Wallop, Bing, Bong, Boom! Digest-digests, digest-digest-digests. Politics? One column, two sentences, a headline! Then, in mid-air, all vanishes!

Bradbury adds a question mark on "Click" and "Politics" despite neither being a question. It is worth noting the quote is dialogue between two characters.

Comment: We can only go by what the author wrote. We can't say he didn't *mean it*. Who says the first two words aren't questions?? The third sentence is just that. All a single utterance. [questions come in many colors]. They can be a single word. See? :)

Comment: Obviously, it's questionable.

Comment: The 50th anniversary edition I found online has slightly different punctuation, oddly.  https://jghsenglish.edublogs.org/files/2015/02/Fahrenheit-451.pdf

Comment: It's perfectly possible in informal speech to imply a question by saying a single word in a questioning tone.

Comment: This is aiming at a particular literary effect, rather than being a normal feature of language (single-word questions are normal, but I can't imagine anyone saying the full paragraph outside of a literary work) in which case it's better asking about the literary techniques on literature SE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verbless sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143488/verbless-sentence) (Crots, sentence fragments [here, interrogative sentence fragments]), used as Stuart says for literary effect. I can't see me getting into the work this is extracted from.