# Is starting your sentence with “Which is why...” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, style-manuals, sentence-starts

Is starting your sentence with “Which is why...” grammatically correct?

> …our brain is still busy processing all the information coming from the phones. **Which is why** it is impossible to actually rest this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verbless sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143488/verbless-sentence) In this case, a  dependent clause is used standalone. This is common in conversation with say prepositional phrases ("On the table, please." / "In the library." ....) But, as here, other sentence fragments are acceptable in informal contexts. Formally, "This is why ..." can be used.

Comment: @PrimeMover We're not allowed to use the word "technically", either, unless we're prepared to quote the technical rule we're alluding to. And "grammatical" is shorter than "grammatically correct", and is not a matter of authority.

Comment: It's perfectly OK. _Which is why it is impossible to actually rest this way_ is non-defining relative clause, where the antecedent of "which" is the preceding clause _our brain ..._. Note that the sequence _why it is impossible to actually rest this way_ is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) meaning  _Which is the answer to the question 'Why is it impossible to actually rest this way?'"

Comment: The _which_ in _Which is why_ simply refers to the previous statement. Which is why you can start the next clause this way; it sounds like a new sentence and may contain a pause, and there are no spaces or punctuation in language, i.e, speech.

Comment: Here's a blog post: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-you-start-a-sentence-with-which

Comment: @StuartF Excellent link. The telling sentence in that blog is: "In summary, you are allowed to use standalone “which” clauses for dramatic effect. Be aware, though, that “which” clauses used in this manner are like hot sauce: you should use them sparingly. If you overuse the technique, it loses its dramatic effect. " I would contend that there's absolutely no reason for artificial "dramatic effect" in OP's example. (IMO it's stylistically ugly, but that's by-the-by.)

Comment: One thing is using "which is why* to emphasize a previous thought, as in giving a speech. another is writing. **Even junior editors know to change this for written texts to**: ***This is why***. And we ain't supposed to be an editing site, are we? In any case, **this question is not a grammar question**. It's an editing question.

Answer (score 2):

John Lawler: The which in Which is why simply refers to the previous statement. Which is why you can start the next clause this way; it sounds like a new sentence and may contain a pause, and there are no spaces or punctuation in language, i.e, speech.

That's right, of course.

And starting a sentence with it is a stylistic choice, and is not grammatically relevant. That said, it is not a written form. Most editors would cross it out and put it: This is why etc.

Furthermore, in the same vein here is the Master's text (John Lawler, in case you're wondering) on punctuation which states among other things:

> [...] punctuation is of recent adoption (Shakespeare’s punctuation,
> for instance, is quite different from Modern English); it is subject
> to great individual variation (like handwriting, or spelling before
> the introduction of printing); and there is no consensus as to how it
> should be used (though there is no shortage of prescriptivist
> fulmination, all incomplete and contradictory in one way or another;
> e.g, Truss 2004). Thus it must also be considered a representational
> system that is still in the process of being standardized, and may not
> in fact ever achieve standardization.
>
> [...] Still another use – indeed, the original use – of punctuation is
> to provide some indication of the *intonational and rhythmic
> intentions of the writer*, as the written words indicate the lexical
> and grammatical intentions.

ERGO, the question about this:
[...]"our brain is still busy processing all the information coming from the phones. **Which is why** it is impossible to actually rest this way". is about punctuation and not grammar."

No one would dispute this if the "which is why" was placed like this:

[...]"our brain is still busy processing all the information coming from the phones **which is why** it is impossible to actually rest this way."

The fact is that *prosodically*, a second sentence could be started by any of the most common relative pronouns: who, whom, whose, which, and that.

Below is a great example of a formal speech by Prodi of the European Commission. It may be a translation, I don't know, but it is nicely done.

> The White Paper lays down five principles: openness, participation,
> accountability, effectiveness and coherence. These principles
> effectively serve to "apply better the fundamental principles of
> subsidiarity and proportionality that underlie our Treaties" and they
> concern all EU institutions.
>
> **Which is why we are seeking to:**
>
> achieve more transparency in the day-to-day application of EU policies
> and greater participation by organised civil society and the
> representatives of municipalities, towns and regions;" [etc.]

[European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/SPEECH_02_344)

All this said, when a text is written to be read by readers, **most editors** would use a period and do this:

"[...]our brain is still busy processing all the information coming from the phones. **This is why** it is impossible to actually rest this way". is about punctuation and not grammar."

So, really this is an editing question and not a grammar question.

Comment: I like your explanation.  Just wanted to comment that in informal writing, such as most blog posts, there would be no need to switch to "This is why."

Comment: Yeah, usually blogs are written in that sort of style. / I'm constantly amazed at how much non-fiction writing has changed over a few generations.

Comment: Bummer.  You know, you can ask here or at ELU Meta why the downvotes.  It doesn't always work but sometimes it does.

Comment: I haven't counted (and don't care), but it may be that using _which is why_ as a summarizing beginning to a final peroration is more common in speech (or in speeches, anyway) than actual writing. Editors have their own standards, which are just another side of the language mountain.

Answer (score 1):

**Which** (relative pronoun) is anaphoric. It can only refer to a noun that has already been mentioned; otherwise it is meaningless.

In current Modern English, it is expected that the referent noun will be part of the same sentence as "which" and that "which" will introduce a subordinate relative clause.

Subordinate clauses are not themselves sentences, thus your example should be marked as wrong.

However, "Which is why..." is commonly used to complete a statement.

[Two instructors A and B address soldiers]

A: "The bullet comes out the barrel at a speed of a little over 800mph."

B: "Which is why you should not look down a barrel."

or ironically to state the obvious:

A: "So, this key that you gave me will unlock the door to the storeroom?"

B: "Which is why I gave it to you... or did you forget? Or perhaps you were not listening?"

Comment: The antecedents of non-defining relative clauses are not restricted to nominals. They can have virtually any element, including clauses, as antecedent. Here, "which" has the preceding clause as antecedent. Common enough and grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

> *…our brain is still busy processing all the information coming from the phones. Which is why it is impossible to actually rest this way.*

It's perfectly OK.

The sequence *Which is why it is impossible to actually rest this way* is a non-defining relative clause where the antecedent of "which" is the preceding clause *our brain .... phones*.

Internally, the sequence *why it is impossible to actually rest this way* is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), so the  meaning can be glossed as

"… *our brain is still busy processing all the information coming from the phones.* *Which is the answer to the question 'Why is it impossible to actually rest this way?'"*

Comment: I think we are agreed as to the function of "which" but we are supposed to be answering "**Is starting your sentence with “Which is why...” grammatically correct?**" You can say "The cup is hot, which was why I dropped it." but you can't idiomatically say "Which is why I dropped it, it was hot."

Comment: @Greybeard If you read the first sentence of my answer, you'll see that I said "It's "perfectly OK". This answers the OP's question "Is starting your sentence with “Which is why...” grammatically correct?"

Comment: @Greybeard It was Lambie, not John Lawler who said that! Read DW256's answer with attested examples.

Comment: In fact, if you read JL's 2nd comment, he actually uses a sentence beginning with "which". You're miles off beam, old chap!

Comment: As I did ......

Comment: @Greybeard Your last but one comment was factually inaccurate Stop posting worthless comments on perfectly good answers.

Comment: One objection I have to your answer is that you have used the fallacy of equivocation and have used **clause** and **sentence** interchangeably: "The sequence *"Which is why it is impossible to actually rest this way"* is a non-defining relative **clause** where the antecedent of "which" is the preceding **clause** *our brain .... phones* - yet the preceding is obviously a sentence. The essence of a relative clause is that it part of a sentence. It has already been pointed out that "This" would be far more acceptable. You may agree that our ideas on language often differ, and that is fine.

Comment: Wake up @Greybeard A sentence is typically either a main clause or a coordination of main clauses. And you still haven't rescinded your earlier remark concerning a comment that you attributed to JL, when in fact it was made by Lambie.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the best way to determine if something is generally grammatical is to ask whether it's used in reputable publications. The answer to that question here is a resounding YES.

The TIME magazine corpus yields 70 hits.

> Oil, gas and coal leases on federal land require a 12.5% gross
> royalty, but hard-rock mining pays nothing to the U.S., and a
> suitability review is an airy dream. **Which is why** mining-industry
> money has watered the grass roots of pro-development " wise use "
> (Mother Lode Vs. Mother Nature, John Skow, 1993)
>
> Critics of Clinton will undoubtedly say that a President with flexible
> beliefs, who once polled voters to decide where he should go on
> vacation, deserves history's inattention. **Which is why** with the
> end of his presidency in sight and the realization that a lame duck's
> influence drops precipitously after his sixth year, Clinton and his
> advisers are feeling the shadow of Reagan and urgently pondering the
> question, What is Clintonism? (Clinton's Last Campaign; KAREN TUMULTY
> AND JAY BRANEGAN; 1998)
>
> Like any Yankee or Marlin, you want to shake the stiffness of winter
> out of your carcass and bound into spring like a line drive. **Which
> is why** following a spring-training regimen of muscle-stretching and
> flexibility exercises can be so important. (Get Spring In Your
> Training; TIM PADGETT; 2006)

COHA (Corpus of Historical American English) yields 400+ hits.

> THERE is a widespread conviction that Bishop William Montgomery Brown
> really is a heretic. But there is another widespread conviction that
> heresy hasn't hurt him any. **Which is why** he stays in the headlines
> even after his case has been " finally closed ". If heresy had broken
> out on the old man, or soured his soul or spoiled his looks, the
> reporters would have noticed it long before this. (New Yorker, 1926)
>
> A good male haircut, it seems, should be a secret that no one's in on
> except man and his barber. **Which is why**, as soon as he sits down
> in the barber chair, he usually warns the barber, " Now go easy? not
> too short!" (Good Housekeeping, 1946)
>
> We're all part of one great machine. So I feel a little ahead of a lot
> of people who don't see that yet. **Which is why** on Sunday morning I
> leave my pajamas on the bathroom floor and sit on the toilet lid
> polishing my low shoes with spit and bits of toilet paper. (Harpers,
> 1968)
>
> Pluralism in Nicaragua would not only be good for Nicaragua, it would
> be good for all of Central America. It would be the only reliable
> guarantor of nonintervention. **Which is why** the proposal made by a
> group of Nicaraguan rebel leaders meeting in early December with
> Special Envoy Richard Stone in Panama is a good one. (The New
> Republic, 1983)
>
> There are, in fact, so many options that the beginner may have trouble
> selecting the best process for the job at hand. **Which is why** we
> selected three different types of home blues for step-by-step
> demonstrations. (Outdoor Life, 1995)
>
> They create a place -- neither esthetic heaven nor didactic classroom
> -- where we can begin to experience another way of being human. **Which is why** we go to the museum in the first place. (NYT, 1996)
>
> This evening the display is washed out and unimpressive, the sun
> veiled by tight-knotted clouds. The crowd is sparse and mumbly with
> disappointment. **Which is why** he's not surprised to find Babs
> there. He spots her with her chest pressed against the steel railing,
> breasts spilling down like batter overrunning a pan. (Southern Review,
> 2002)

The British National Corpus yields 106 hits.

> Many of the symptoms shown by food-intolerant and chemical-sensitive
> patients are symptoms that we all suffer from at times -- headaches,
> tiredness and indigestion for example. **Which is why** some doctors
> feel that such patients are' not really ill', simply over-reacting to
> everyday symptoms. (The complete guide to food allergy and
> intolerance. Gamlin, Linda and Brostoff, Jonathan; 1989)
>
> Orchestral players themselves don't necessarily lead the healthiest
> lives! And yet they are under enormous stress when they are doing
> their best work. An orchestral player works as hard as a navvy.
> **Which is why** I have always tried to insist that my players have proper ways of relaxing away from their work. (Conversations with
> Karajan. Osborne, Richard. Oxford; 1991)
>
> Price-resistance, payment problems, piracy -- in many parts of the
> world, no matter how great the aspirations of the local population,
> plans to supply demand can rapidly turn from opportunity to threat.
> **Which is why** so often the thoughts of publishers return to Europe, by which is generally meant the mature markets of southern Europe,
> Greece, Spain and Italy. (Bookseller. London: J Whitaker & sons, 1993)

The iWeb corpus yields 16501 hits.

It is quite clearly an accepted way to start a sentence in English, and thus grammatical. Any explanation as to why is secondary to the fact that it is in common use in respected publications.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I can scarcely believe the two answers that claim otherwise.

Comment: **The use is dependent on the preceding sentence**.

Comment: @Lambie I fail to see how that has any relevance to the question at hand. The use of many a connective item depends on the preceding sentence(s): _therefore, though, in contrast, as a result_, anything containing a pronoun referring to the preceding sentence(s), etc. The potential list is nearly endless. Here we are only concerned with whether this particular string is a grammatical way to start a sentence. The evidence resoundingly confirms that it is grammatical, even common, to do so.

Comment: It is relevant because without it, the which string (your term) would be senseless. I could not start an essay with that at the beginning.....For example, a first sentence in an essay like this: **Which we thought of as important for history**. Impossible, right? People here seem to want to eschew the obvious link between these which clauses and what precedes them.

Answer (score -4):

According to other contributors on this site, it's "perfectly okay", but it *does* need to be pointed out that it is not grammatically correct.

The second "sentence" is a subordinate clause which does not have a main clause, and so is technically a sentence fragment.

If you're down the pub bantering to your mates then I expect few people would care to express their concern on the matter, but in more formal contexts, for example a technical exposition, then it is, IMESVHO, "better" to be as formally grammatically correct as possible, especially if you want learned people to take you seriously.

Comment: "Which is why it is impossible to actually rest this way" **is** a sentence if you take account of the function/antecedent  of "which".

Comment: @Lambie So what is the "correct" way to look at this? I thought one was not allowed to talk about "right" or "wrong" on this forum.